# How convert some value to json by Newtonsoft?

Tags: c#, json

i have code return "Datatable ","Datatable" content idstudent , avg , firstname ,namecourse  and date, this "Datatable" content more row .

```
 DataTable row = mn.selectProgram("programStudent", attributes);
                JsonTrans responce = new JsonTrans();
                responce.Convert(row);
                 //if (row.Rows.Count != 0)
            //{
            //    foreach (DataRow result in row.Rows)
            //    {
            //        string idstudent = result["id"].ToString();

            //        string avgstudent = result["AVG"].ToString();
            //        string firstname = result["fname"].ToString();
            //        string date = result["date"].ToString();
            //        string namecourse = result["name"].ToString();


            //    }


            //}
```

i try  :

```
public string Convert(DataTable row)
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            StringWriter sw = new StringWriter(sb);
            JsonWriter jsonWriter = new JsonTextWriter(sw);
            jsonWriter.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
            jsonWriter.WriteStartArray();
            if (row.Rows.Count != 0)
            {
                foreach (DataRow result in row.Rows)
                {
                    jsonWriter.WriteStartObject();
                    string idstudent = result["id"].ToString();
                    jsonWriter.WritePropertyName("id");
                    jsonWriter.WriteValue(idstudent);
                    jsonWriter.WriteEndObject();
                }

            }
            jsonWriter.WriteEndArray();
            jsonWriter.Close();
            sw.Close();
```

How can convert this row to json like to :

```
    [ {idstudent:"value" ,avg :"value" , avg : "value",firstname :"value"}
      {idstudent:"value" ,avg :"value" , avg : "value",firstname :"value"}   
      {idstudent:"value" ,avg :"value" , avg : "value",firstname :"value"}  ]
```

Comment: Did you actually try something?

Comment: yes ,but i do not know how convert same that form  by Newtonsoft .

Comment: because i want send this json to android .

Comment: Well, show us what you tried. Nothing in your code snippet shows any effort. Also your required output is invalid. Why do you have the `avg` filed double? And what is `JsonTrans`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your code is very close to what you're trying to accomplish.  If you want every column present in your DataRows, your foreach loop should iterate through all of the table's columns.  (Note that I have changed your *DataTable* name here to **table** for clarity, and the *DataRow* name to **row**.)

```
            foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
            {
                jsonWriter.WriteStartObject();
                foreach (DataColumn col in table.Columns)
                {
                    jsonWriter.WritePropertyName(col.ColumnName);
                    jsonWriter.WriteValue((row[col.ColumnName] == null) ? string.Empty : row[col.ColumnName].ToString());
                }
                jsonWriter.WriteEndObject();
            }
```

Note that this example will write out empty strings where the source data is null.  If you want to leave null values out entirely, perform the check for (row[col.ColumnName] == null)  prior to writing the property name and value.